# Tensorflow & Node: ...server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, importerror

I am currently trying to follow along to a tutorial using tensorflow & js to make a handwriting detection AI, but am having some trouble with imports. Previously, I wasn't able to import the bootstrap.css file, but have found a work around in the html. The following correctly imports the css file and applies it to the DOM:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" 
                type = "text/css" 
                href = "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" 
                media = "screen"/>
```

However, when I try this for the tfjs import, I am unable to give the import a variable (which I want to set as 'tf')

```
<html type = "module"
                src = "../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs"
                defer> </html>
```

The file paths are correct, but I cannot access tfjs's code.
defer>

When attempting to do so, I get the following error:

```
localhost/:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Here is my file directory:
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPkpB.png)

And here are my import statements in main.js:

```
// import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
// ^^ replaced by using import statement in html
import * as tf from '../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { MNIST_DATA } from './data.js';
```

```js
import * as tf from '../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { MNIST_DATA } from './data.js';

console.log("main script loaded...");

var model;

function create () {

    model = tf.sequential();

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({

        inputShape: [28, 28, 1],
        kernelSize: 5,
        filter: 8,
        strides: 1,
        activation: 'relu',
        kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({

        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2, 2],

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({

        kernelSize: 5,
        filter: 16,
        strides: 1,
        activation: 'relu',
        kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({

        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2, 2],

    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.flatten());

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({

        units: 10,
        kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
        activation: 'softmax',

    }));


    model.compile({

        optimizer: tf.train.sgd(.15),
        loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',

    });


}

create();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html leng = "en">

    <head>
    
        <link rel = "stylesheet" 
                type = "text/css" 
                href = "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" 
                media = "screen"/>
    
        <script type = "module"
                src = "main.js"
                defer> </script>

        <!-- <html type = "module"
                src = "../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs"
                defer> </html> -->
    
        <meta charset  = "utf-8">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <style>
    
            .prediction-canvas {
    
                width: 100px;
                margin: 20px;
    
            }
    
            .prediction-div {
    
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 10px;
    
            }
    
        </style>

        <div class = "container" style = "padding-top: 20px;">

            <div class = "card">

                <div class = "card-header">

                    <strong> Alpha Vision </strong>

                </div>

                <div class = "card-body">

                    <div class = "card">

                        <div class = "card-body">

                            <h5 class = "card-title">

                                <strong> log </strong>
                                <div id = "log"> </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class = "card">

                        <div class = "card-body">

                            <h5 class = "card-title"> predict </h5>

                            <button type= "button" 
                                    class = "btn btn-primary" 
                                    id = "selectTestDataButton"
                                    disabled> waiting for model... </button>

                            <div id = "predictionResult"> </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

I tried looking at posts here with similar errors, but all had to do with angular and server-side code, rather than tfjs & node modules.
Does anyone know of a way to import a module and assign it a value for JS in the index.html, or why my error is occuring? I am unable to create a model without this module.

If I need to include any other details, please let me know! Thanks in advance!